# Using a grails/groovy class by reference

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to create my own CRUD controller in grails for the stuff that the scaffolding won't do.

Instead of maintaining code for a controller for each domain, I'd like to have one controller that can look after any domain for the generic CRUD calls.. as the only difference is the domain class name.

Using the example of domain class Job & Note

Instead of

```
Job.get(id)
Job.list()
def instance = new Job(params)

Note.get(id)
Note.list()
def instance = new Job(params)
```

I was thinking of

```
def someHandler = Job // configurable

someHandler.get(id)
someHandler.list()
def instance = new someHandler(params)
```

The first two static methods work fine (get, list) but creating a new instance does not.
Any pointers as to how to best do this.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Call the default constructor using

```
def instance = someHandler.newInstance()
```

and the constructor for params using

```
def instance = someHandler.newInstance(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not happy with the scaffolded controllers/views that Grails provides by default, and want to change them in a similar fashion for all domain classes, a better approach might be to simply edit the templates that are used to generate these controllers/views.

You can do this by running the script `grails install-templates`. This will create a number of files in the `src/templates/scaffolding` directory, each of which defines the template used to generate a scaffolded artifact.

Change these templates to create the controllers/views that you want. If you've already run `grails generate-all` for any domain classes, you'll need to run it again for those classes to update the existing scaffolding.